# test results aggregator Jenkins plugin - No Job Found message

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I installed [test results aggregator](https://github.com/jenkinsci/test-results-aggregator-plugin) Jenkins plugin and then ran a free-style job with two test jobs test1 and test2.
The plugin reports that test1 and test2 jobs were not found, but these jobs exist. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
15:37:04 Collecting Data from Jenkins Job with name 'test1' ...Job Not Found
15:37:04 Collecting Data from Jenkins Job with name 'test2' ...Job Not Found
15:37:04 Analyze ...Finished
15:37:04 Generate XML Report...Finished XML Report
15:37:04 Generate HTML Report...Finished HTML Report
15:37:04 Generate HTML Report...Finished HTML Report
15:37:04 Generate Email Report
15:37:04 No mail will be Send since all Jobs are having status 'NOT_FOUND'.
15:37:04 Generate Email Report
15:37:04 No mail will be Send since all Jobs are having status 'NOT_FOUND'.
15:37:04 Post Influx DB
15:37:04 Finished Aggregate Test Results Action
15:37:04 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. One possible sollution (that didn't work for me) is to check if the path to the jobs is correct. Maybe your folder structure is not correctly mapped and Jenkins doesn't find it.

Comment: the plugin page says "After installing this plugin, navigate to Global Configuration. Scroll down for Test Result Aggregator :"

do we need to do this Global configuration as shown in this screenshot?
https://github.com/jenkinsci/test-results-aggregator-plugin/blob/master/screenshots/Global_Configuration.png

Is this a security concern to provide these credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
After installing this plugin, navigate to Global Configuration.
Scroll down for Test Result Aggregator.
Enter the Jenkins base URL, username, and password.

See the screenshot of the Global configuration here:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/test-results-aggregator-plugin/blob/master/screenshots/Global_Configuration.png